# Gradle Build is getting exit code error spot bug task

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, spotbugs

This is my configuration.Keeping it brief only for spotbug configuration

```
plugins{
  id "com.github.spotbugs" version "6.0.3"
}
// Spotbugs Plugin Configuration
spotbugs {
    toolVersion = "4.8.3"
    ignoreFailures = true
    excludeFilter = file("${projectDir}/static-code-analysis/spotbugs/exclude.xml")
    spotbugsTest.enabled = false
}

spotbugsMain {
    reports.create("html") {
            required = true
            outputLocation = file("$buildDir/reports/spotbugs/main/spotbugs.html")
            stylesheet = 'fancy-hist.xsl'
    }
}
```

Tool version:

```
 Spring 3.1.8
 Java 17 (eclipse temurin) 
 Gradle 7.6.1
```

Error:

> Blockquote
> 2024-01-25T17:25:59.282-0600 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] > Task :spotbugsMain
> 2024-01-25T17:26:21.179-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED
> 2024-01-25T17:26:21.179-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.7.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe'' finished with exit value 1 (state: FAILED)
> 2024-01-25T17:26:21.179-0600 [WARN] [com.github.spotbugs.snom.internal.SpotBugsRunnerForHybrid$SpotBugsExecutor$Inject] SpotBugs ended with exit code 1

Can someone suggest what is issue here, build is fine but this error is giving issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is because the build does not fail when bugs are found with `ignoreFailures = true`. From [this test](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/blob/20a9ecb72b6e81ae773d5a38521b8acea88295cf/src/functionalTest/groovy/com/github/spotbugs/snom/StandardFunctionalTest.groovy#L260).